# Hash table memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, hashtable

I have a basic hash table implementation and when I run it, all is fine but 
valgrind says that I have lost some memory.

```
==11454== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11454==     in use at exit: 136 bytes in 1 blocks
==11454==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 9 frees, 224 bytes allocated
==11454== 
==11454== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11454==    definitely lost: 136 bytes in 1 blocks
==11454==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11454==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11454==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11454==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

I think it may be due to the way I'm allocating memory to my keys pointer. Here is my code for the 
table:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "htable.h"
#include "mylib.h"

struct htablerec {

  int capacity;
  int num_keys;
  char **keys;

};

static unsigned int htable_word_to_int(char *word) {
  unsigned int result = 0;
  while (*word != '\0') {
    result = (*word++ + 31 * result);
  }
  return result;
}

static unsigned int htable_hash(htable h, unsigned int i_key) {
  return i_key % h->capacity;
}

htable htable_new(int capacity) {

  int i;
  htable result = emalloc(sizeof *result);
  result->capacity = capacity;
  result->num_keys = 0;
  result->keys = emalloc(capacity * sizeof result->keys[0]);

  for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {

    result->keys[i] = NULL;
  }

  return result;
}

void htable_free(htable h) {

  int i;
l

  for (i = 0; i < h->capacity; i++) {

    free(h->keys[i]);
  }

  free(h);
}

int htable_insert(htable h, char *key) {

  unsigned int index = htable_word_to_int(key) % h->capacity;

  if (h->num_keys == h->capacity) {
    return 0;
  }
  for (;;) {

    if (NULL == h->keys[index]) {

      h->keys[index] = emalloc(sizeof(key));
      strcpy(h->keys[index], key);
      h->num_keys++;

      return 1;
    }
    if (strcmp(h->keys[index], key) == 0) {

      return 1;
    }
    index = htable_hash(h, index + 1);
  }
}

void htable_print(htable h, FILE *stream) {

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < h->capacity; i++) {
    fprintf(stream, "%2d %s\n", i, h->keys[i] == NULL ? "" : h->keys[i]);
  }
}
```

The emalloc function just uses malloc and checks whether it allocated memory properly. Also, in my
insert function, I emalloc the size of key. But key is a pointer, so shouldn't that give me the size
of the pointer not of the word?

Comment: Valgrind probably tells you to re-run it with `--leak-check=full` to learn where the leaked memory was allocated. Do that.

Comment: BTW, `h->keys[index] = emalloc(sizeof(key));` is not right. Since you are calling `strcpy` right after it, you should use `h->keys[index] = emalloc(strlen(key)+1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I think it may be due to the way I'm allocating memory to my keys pointer."

Actually, you're allocating the keys pointer correctly. Its the lack of `free()`ing it that seems to be your downfall:

```
result->keys = emalloc(capacity * sizeof result->keys[0]);
```

needs to be `free()`ed somewhere. Such as:

```
void htable_free(htable h) 
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < h->capacity; i++)
   {
       free(h->keys[i]);
   }
   free(h->keys); // NOTE: h->keys freed here.
   free(h);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that, completely missed it. In my for loop, I'm not too sure why I allocate it with sizeof key rather than sizeof *key. Doesn't sizeof *key give the size of the actual char array?

Comment: @Paldan your allocation is correct as-is. It says "give me memory capable of holding `capacity` number of items of the size of the thing my `keys` member holds". Note: `emalloc(capacity * sizeof *(result->keys));` would also have worked.

Comment: Hey thanks, I realize that the part you mentioned is right, but I'm more confused about the part in the infinite for loop in the insert function (I should have been more specific).

Comment: @Paldan yeah, ok. I see what you mean now. That for-loop should be only running up to capacity, and if reached, expand the table, rehome the current content by sending it through the hash function, then repeat the chaining process. Pretty sure thats part of your assignment, but you're correct in pointing out that infinite loop can eventually exceed your chain if left unchecked and you keep piling in data. It should be addressed, and your intuition it isn't complete yet is spot-on.